# What classifiers to use for deciding if two datasets depict the same individual?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, classification

Suppose I have pictures of faces of a set of individuals. The question I'm trying to answer is: "do these two pictures represent the same individual"?

As usual, I have a training set containing several pictures for a number of individuals. The individuals and pictures the algorithm will have to process are of course not in the training set.

My question is not about image processing algorithms or particular features I should use, but on the issue of classification. **I don't see how traditional classifier algorithms such as SVM or Adaboost can be used in this context. How should I use them? Should I use other classifiers? Which ones?**

NB: my real application is not faces (I don't want to disclose it), but it's close enough.

Note: the training dataset isn't enormous, in the low thousands at best. Each dataset is pretty big though (a few megabytes), even if it doesn't hold a lot of real information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably look at the following methods:

- P. Jonathon Phillips: Support Vector Machines Applied to Face Recognition. NIPS 1998: 803-809
- Haibin Ling, Stefano Soatto, Narayanan Ramanathan, and David W.
  Jacobs, A Study of Face Recognition as People Age, IEEE International
  Conference on Computer Vision (ICCV), 2007.

These methods describe using SVMs to same person/different person problems like the one you describe. If the alignment of the features (eyes, nose, mouth) is good, these methods work very nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I'll read the papers and report back.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. These papers are exactly what I needed. For the record, the solution is to perform classification in difference space, where the difference is an abstract symmetrical functional that takes two images and returns difference features. This difference can be a simple absolute difference of two images, or something more complex, as shown in the second paper.

Answer (score 1):

How big is your dataset?
I would start this problem  by coming up with some kind of distance metric (say euclidean) that would characterize differences between image(such as differences in color,shape etc. or say local differences)..Two image representing same individual would have small distance as compared to image representing different individual..though  it would highly depend on the type of data set you are currently working.

Comment: The training dataset isn't enormous, in the low thousands at the very best.

Comment: A metric isn't hard to come by, for faces I could use euclidean distance between eigenfaces for example. My problem is about the final classification step, not the previous steps.

Comment: If the distance between two faces is low, then they are likely to represent the same individual (how likely? you find this from your training set).  Then the problem is trivially reduced to "Are these two faces close together by my metric?"  If this doesn't give good enough results, you need to come up with a better metric.  That **should** be the hard part, I don't know why you think that "isn't hard to come by".

Comment: No, my problem is where to set the threshold. I want the threshold to be set automatically and not manually. The metric is a hard problem, but there is a lot of literature adressing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for stating the obvious, but why not use any supervised classifier (SVM, GMM, k-NN, etc.), get one label for each test sample (e.g., face, voice, text, etc.), and then see if the two labels match?

Otherwise, you could perform a binary hypothesis test. H0 = two samples do not match. H1 = two samples match. For two test samples, x1 and x2, compute a distance, d(x1, x2). Choose H1 if d(x1, x2) < epsilon and H0 otherwise. Adjusting epsilon will adjust your probability of detection and probability of false alarm. Your application would dictate which epsilon is best; for example, maybe you can tolerate misses but cannot tolerate false alarms, or vice versa. This is called Neyman-Pearson hypothesis testing.

Comment: For the first part of your answer: the problem (if I understand your answer correctly) is that the subjects to test are not in the training database. And I don't think I can afford to re-train everytime I have to test an image pair.

Comment: Concerning the second part of your comment: this is pretty much the conclusion I arrived to, but I was wondering: (1) if there are good ways of setting the epsilon automatically, and (2), if there is a way to use a classifier on the multi-dimensional input directly, instead of computing a metric and thresholding on the metric. Intuitively, it seems to me that (2) should be able to get better results.